# How to solve the error message: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'BlobPart'

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular10

I have the following function call

```
this.component.getXML({ format: true }, (error, currentXML) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }

  // do something with currentXML
});
```

But I want to use `async` `await` to solve a task, in order to do this I do the following

```
async function someName() {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.component.getXML({ format: true }, (error, currentXML) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      }

      resolve(currentXML);
    });
  });

  try {
    const currentXML = await promise;

    const blob = new Blob([currentXML], { type: "text/xml" });
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", blob, "filename.xml");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
}
```

This works. My problem is that when trying to build the blob `const blob = new Blob([currentXML], { type: "text/xml" });` it gives me this error message

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'BlobPart'
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Blob': size, type, arrayBuffer, slice, and 2 more.
```

The output of calling `const currentXML = await promise;` is a string, I have tried to define it explicitly but the error persists

Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I got to solve this problem by adding type `Promise<string>` in this way

```
const promise: Promise<string> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.modeler.saveXML({ format: true }, (error, updatedXML) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    }

    resolve(updatedXML);
  });
});
```